# adding string object to gArray

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gnome

I want to add some string objects in GArray. But when i read the API manual of

g_array_new(), it seeks the size of the element to be added while creating the array, but

different string objects have different length, so how can i cope with this issue.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the size of the element is:

```
sizeof(gchar*)
```

You put into array not the actual string, but the **pointer** to a string.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [GPtrArray](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html), not GArray.